# HTTP request payload mapping to class in Spring

Tags: spring-integration

I've created a Feed class in my Spring Integration project, with a view to mapping any payloads that contain feed in them to my class. I can't use spring's proprietary atom feed message converter, as we have different format requirements.

The problem I have is that the payload keeps getting converted to the proprietary feed class instead of the one that I wrote, when I submit a post with a payload. I suppose the big issue here is that both the spring atom message converter, and mine define a "Feed" class.

So, is there any way to force spring to use my Feed class, instead of it's own Feed class when processing the payload?

Many thanks,
R.

PS: I tried setting the request-payload-type to my own class name, without success.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Integration feed module doesn't support pluggable converters.

If you use the http outbound gateway, you can configure a custom Message converter into the underlying RestTemplate. By default, it will use the AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter if rome is on the classpath.